# Correlation coeffcient expressed in a different form

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

If $X_j = a + bX_i$ and $X_i = a' + b'X_j$ how does one show that the correlation coefficient can be written as: $\rho_{i,j} = b \frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_j}=b'\frac{\sigma_j}{\sigma_i}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$b=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma^2_X}$ and $\rho_{ij}=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$, then

$$
\rho_{ij}=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} = \frac{\sigma_X cov(X,Y)}{\sigma^2_X \sigma_Y} = b\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}
$$

Comment: where can I read up on this result: $b = \frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma^2_X}$. Or perhaps you could extend on that? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_regression_model